# Java: How to return declared type in interface hierarchy?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface hierarchy similar to -

```
interface Type
{
    Type copy();
};

interface SubType extends Type
{
};

interface SubSubType extends SubType
{
};
```

And a concrete class

```
public class Concrete implements SubSubType
{
    @Override public Concrete copy() { return new Concrete(); }
}
```

I would like to be able to call copy() on a Type and get a Type back, call copy() on a SubType and get a SubType back, etc. Is this achievable? Possibly with generics?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like so:

```
public interface Type { 
  public Type copy();
}

public interface SubType extends Type { 
  public SubType copy();
}

public class Concrete implements Type { 
  @Override
  public Concrete copy() {
    return new Concrete();
  }
}

public class SubConcrete implements SubType {
  @Override
  public SubConcrete copy() {
    return new SubConcrete();
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Type    type    = new Concrete();
  SubType subType = new SubConcrete();

  Type    newType    = type.copy();
  SubType newSubType = subType.copy();
}
```

Comment: Is this legal?  How does it know if you are returning a Type (as declared in the Type interface) or a SubType (as declared in the SubType interface)?  You are overloading by the return type which is unusual.  (Is this something new in Java 7, or am I really behind the times?)

Comment: @user: It was new in Java 5.  It's called [return type covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).  The compiler will consider the static return type to be the return type of the declared type of the variable you're calling `copy()` on.  In other words, if you have a `Type type = new SubConcrete();` you can't do `SubType subType = type.copy()` without a cast.

Comment: @Mark Peters   thanks!  Still strikes me as possibly confusing, but I can see where it could be useful.  IMO, my solution is clearer (and more explicit).  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could go

```
interface <T extends Type> Type {
   T copy();
}

interface SubType extends Type<SubType> {
  // any extra methods here
}
```

then, the implementations will be

```
public class Concrete implements SubType {
   public SubType copy() {
      // code here
   }
}
```

For the record, calling the method copy() when it doesn't copy anything is a very bad idea.

EDIT: Corrected code below.  For simplicity, the SubXXX interfaces are put in as inner classes, in practice this is unlikely to make sense.  Obviously I needed to switch the order.  Duh!

```
public interface Type<T extends Type<?>> {
   T copy();

   public interface SubType<T extends SubType<?>> extends Type<T> {      
   }

   public interface SubSubType extends SubType<SubSubType> {      
   }
}
```

and, an implementation might look like:

```
   class Concrete implements SubType<Concrete> {

      @Override
      public Concrete copy() {
         return new Concrete();
      }     
   }
```

This does look pretty messy, and I prefer (and just voted for) @Tim Pote answer.

Comment: Does this even compile: `interface <T extends Type> Type`?  Doesn't seem to for me.  And if you change it to `interface Type <T extends Type>` you'll get a compiler warning, which you can fix by doing this: `interface Type<T extends Type<?>>`.  However, it'll be more confusing on `SubType`, and more confusing still on `SubSubType`.

Comment: I'm not at my computer with a compiler so it will have to wait till tomorrow to check it out on the details.  But I've done similar things in the past.

Comment: it should just be `interface Type<T>`. and then `interface SubType extends Type<SubType>`

Comment: @newacct what about the `SubSubType`?

Comment: @VictorWong: You're out of luck. There's no general way to return the "self type". `SubSubType` will also have to be `Type<T>`, which technically works, but probably not what you wanted.